# 1 File - Direct Access - External User

Tags: sharepoint-online, access

Is it possible to just have only one file given access to an external user, and no other access? What I mean is the file that I want them to access is about 5 levels of folders, instead of this external person clicking on each folder to get to the file, perhaps there is a way that allows just only this file to show under "documents" when they come to our SharePoint Online site. Thoughts? Otherwise I have to allow them to view only the folder structure to actually see the file when they login. Thanks.

Comment: why would they need to see the folder structure or the library? You can share the file with them and then they can access the file. You don't need to give them access to the site.

Comment: We have multiple domains that will be collaborating. The problem is I am trying to keep this the best way possible to manage. In other words, for tighter security I don't want them to have a link, or to share link. I want to specifiy what file they have access to, and when they go to our sharepoint, that is the only file or folders that shows up. It would be nice if it is a situation where there is only one file they need to update and input data, that they don't have to open up the sharepoint and drill down 5 folders just to get to that one spreadsheet they need to update.

Comment: Create a view without folders.

Comment: Thanks, if i create a view without folders, can it be defined by groups as to which view they use? in other words lets just say i have abou 50 external users from 5 different domains, but have them all split up into different groups,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is doable. Although it requires few configurations.

1. Tenant Level Sharing Policy: Use this policy to define, what level Sharing is permitted in your organization. If your organization allow, you can set it to `Anyone` which means, anyone with the link can access the shared content. I am using `New and Existing guest users`, so they need to sign in before accessing the content.
   [image]
2. Site Collection Level Sharing: By default, the site collection is set to only people in organization. Change it to `New and existing guest`.
   [image]
3. Finally Document level Sharing: To share to external users, go to the document you like share, and click on Share button/icon using command bar or context menu. From the popup, update link setting to `Specific people`, you can allow editing or downloading of document here or simply turn it off, based on your requirement. Click `Apply` button, and now add the external user Email ID. A mail will be sent to the email id you specify. Refer to the [video](https://www.thinkb4code.com/sp-share/).

Comment: Thanks, already got it set to new and existing guests. I do not want to share links, i'd prefer direct access and the reason being is, lets say that person leaves and new person comes along, all i have to do is put that new external email address user into that group, and the permissions is complete.

Comment: If you watched the video, I paused it and copied the link from external user mail box. There are other stuff also going in that mail box, which I dont want to show, so removed that part. Since the link is created with read only access, next time click on 'Share' icon, click on ellipsis on top right corner of card, and click 'Manage Access'. Now click on the that ellipsis next to shared link and from the UI add another user. This will trigger a mail to user inbox.

Comment: https://www.thinkb4code.com/sp-share-part-2/

Comment: thanks for your comment, the problem is the link, need this to work via direct access by groups, and if they external user is in that group then allow them only certain things

Comment: I just have one question to you, so the problem you are trying to solve is, add external user to one SP Group, which will give them direct access to the file only. Okay, but how external user will navigate to that file, will they get a mail, or is it something like quick link on a page?

Comment: Basically the way the have direct access to the file only is they can actually only view the folder, nothing else in the folder, but i have to start at the root and there is 5 levels of folders,

Comment: so i have to put view instead of edit, then when i get to the specific file they need, i change the to edit, whereas if i change the folder to edit in which contains the file that would give them the opportunity to delete the folder. They will get instructions from me that this is our sharepoint site at this particular link, and they will have to enroll or use a link just one time only and once they are in the directly, then when the click documents on the left hand side, that will be all they can see.

Comment: They can navigate to it currently as we speak, but when I was playing around this, i thought I had it at one time where it showed only the file they needed to access without the need to drill down to the folders, does that make sense? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I got a better understanding now. A solution for this can be SharePoint Search. Create a SPO Group let say `All External User` and start adding external user to it. Now break document or folder level permission and add this group where ever required. Finally create a page, put a community search webpart (SPO OOB not yet available). Now grant this group access to this page too or user permission level. Now you create a query like `ContentTypeId:0x0101* -ContentType:Folder`. This will show all the documents only.

Answer (score 0):

To grant direct access to an external user to a document, just navigate to the document and click Share > Link settings > **Specific people** > Enter email address and then send link.

The external user will not have access to the document library or the folder containing this document. The link will redirect the user to the shared document in opened status.

On the other hand, I don’t think your requirement is achievable since you need to grant the user access permission of the document library for him to see “only this file to show under ‘documents’”. The folder containing the document will not be invisible in this scenario.

References:

[Collaborate with guests on a document.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Office365/Enterprise/collaborate-on-documents)

[Share SharePoint files or folders.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/share-sharepoint-files-or-folders-1fe37332-0f9a-4719-970e-d2578da4941c)